# What does it mean if tire sidewall height isn't shown? E.g. 215R15

Tags: tires

What does it mean if the tire size doesn't list the sidewall height. For example, apparently I can use 225/70R15 or 215R15. But I am not sure why the second one doesn't list the sidewall height.

The rim size is the same and the tire is only slightly thinner, but what about the height? Will this tire be suitable?

Comment: Never seen a tire without that height info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://www.moderntiredealer.com/article/311243/understanding-tire-dimensions)

> European metric, also called metric, is similar. No letter "P" is used as a prefix. The three-digit number at the beginning indicates cross section in millimeters. If the aspect ratio is lower than 82, the aspect ratio number will follow the section width number. If not, then no aspect ratio number will appear.

So it will have an 82% aspect ratio.